# Paper.js Future Splash

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to make a paper.js example but my problem is that I don't know how to make it work without `<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas-1">`. The script works but I would like to put the js separate to html.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLd7nana/)

Thank you

Comment: Note: "Future Splash Animator" is the original name of "Macromedia Flash" later called "Adobe Flash".

Comment: Maybe you can find some hints [here](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/working-with-paper-js/) for including external js file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use external js file as

`<script type="text/paperscript" src="js/script.js" canvas="canvas-1">`.